# when pid column of sys.session will be null in mysql?

Tags: mysql, session, pid, sys

Am using mysql 5.7.19-log server, i am working on application monitor tool where i need to monitor session details of a mysql server. In the process came to know that pid column can be null in sys.session table. i want to know what are the cases in which pid can be null?

when i exec desc session in mysql shell result as follows:

````
mysql>desc session;
+------------------------+------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type                                     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| thd_id                 | bigint(20) unsigned                      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| conn_id                | bigint(20) unsigned                      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| user                   | varchar(128)                             | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| db                     | varchar(64)                              | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| command                | varchar(16)                              | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| state                  | varchar(64)                              | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| time                   | bigint(20)                               | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| current_statement      | longtext                                 | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| statement_latency      | text                                     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| progress               | decimal(26,2)                            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| lock_latency           | text                                     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| rows_examined          | bigint(20) unsigned                      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| rows_sent              | bigint(20) unsigned                      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| rows_affected          | bigint(20) unsigned                      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tmp_tables             | bigint(20) unsigned                      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tmp_disk_tables        | bigint(20) unsigned                      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| full_scan              | varchar(3)                               | NO   |     |         |       |
| last_statement         | longtext                                 | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| last_statement_latency | text                                     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| current_memory         | text                                     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| last_wait              | varchar(128)                             | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| last_wait_latency      | text                                     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| source                 | varchar(64)                              | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| trx_latency            | text                                     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| trx_state              | enum('ACTIVE','COMMITTED','ROLLED BACK') | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| trx_autocommit         | enum('YES','NO')                         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pid                    | varchar(1024)                            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| program_name           | varchar(1024)                            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------------+------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
28 rows in set (0.00 sec)```
````

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, You need to check the column with the name `Null`. It says that whether the value of a field can be null or not. In your case, `pid` can be `null` because as per the description of a table, `pid` allows `Null`.

Possibilities of `pid` can be the `null` are followed.

- 1. Inserting `pid` as `null` value

```
 INSERT INTO session (pid, program_name) values (null, 'test1'); // pid: null
```

- 2. Don't inserting `pid`

```
 INSERT INTO session (program_name) values ('test1'); // pid: null
```

- 3. Updating `pid` as `null` value

```
 UPDATE session SET pid = null WHERE `thd_id` = 1; // pid: null
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but my actual question is "in real-time setup what are the cases that PID will be null not by inserting, updating etc.." 
For more detail:
when will a row be inserted by mysql server into session table with PID column as null?

Comment: @manvith It's doesn't make sense..The `pId` can be `null` in the above scenarios which I already mentioned.

Comment: what you said is correct only my actual question is "what are the use-cases PID column will become null while the mysql server is running?"
For example: if you connect to a postgres server with unix socket then the PID will become null. - like that uses cases am asking.